# Chicken and egg problem (restore database) when trying to write unit test against SQl Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection, database-restore

Ok, they are not unit tests but end-to-end tests. The setup is somewhat involved. Unit tests will use C#, ODBC connection. Every unit tests will try to clean up after itself, but every 20 tests or so (once per C# class) we would need to do a full database restore. I do not think I can do it over an ODBC connection, according to this document:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/Obtain_Exclusive_Access_to_Restore_SQL_Server_p1.aspx

> Msg 6104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot use KILL to kill your own
>   process.

However, I would like to, so that 199 tests do not go amok because of a bad clean-up. Is there another way? Perhaps I can open a different "connection" such as use COM automation or something of that sort, and then kill all database connections from there? If so, how can I do that?

Also, will the clients be able to re-connect automatically after a restore, or would I have to dismantle everything once every 20 tests or so?

If you find this question confusing, please let me know what your questions are. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note on terminology - if your unit tests aren't just testing a single unit, they're not unit tests.  In this case, because you're testing units and their reliance on other units (code/classes relying on a database) at the same time, you'd refer to this as an "integration test".

Answer (score 1):

If you can make sure you can properly close your ODBC connections, for the purpose of your C# integration tests you could use ADO.NET directly to perform the restore on a new connection from the pool.

I think if you switch you restoring from snapshots rather than full backups, you might find t much faster.

Comment: I am a noob at this, and having more details would be of very much help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can restore from an ODBC connection. You cannot restore if you are use-ing the databse you are trying to restore, but is trivial to change context to `tempdb` or `master`:

```
USE [tempdb];
RESTORE DATABASE foo FROM ...;
```

If there are other connections that use the database, they would be your *own* connections, so its just a matter of making sure you close them properly. If you use connection pooling, clean the pool. `SqlClient` uses [`SqlConnectionClearAllPools`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx), ODBC uses [OdbcConnection.ReleaseObjectPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.releaseobjectpool.aspx) to a somehow similar effect. Point is that is all under your control.

BTW, any reason why you use ODBC and not SqlClient?

Comment: I joined an exiting large project, but I think it is because we also support Oracle and Sybase connections. Thanks for the info! I might want to kill some of the existing connections in a non-graceful way, because the large app consists of several different processes, it has been made for a long while without any testing in mind.